# About steam-user module on csgo

Tags: javascript

I am logging in to steam by entering username and password and logging into csgo. And I want to login to a community server by sending a message to the console or by direct command, but I guess the "steam-user" module does not support this. Can you suggest another module code that is compatible with this module?

```
steam.gamesPlayed([730]);

steam.on('appLaunched', (appid) => {
    console.log("Game is started: ", appid);
```

I tried to use sendtoGC command but I still do not know how it is working. I am waiting for your reply.

I am trying to join steam by username and password. Then starting csgo and connect a community server by ip and port. But I couldn't send a connect command to console or directly connect server.